# bad gateway errors - fiddler load testing / visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, fiddler, load-testing

I set up two tests for a web service hosted on a remote server to measure loadtesting : one used a web tool (Fiddler with StresStimulus) to create multiple request tests to the server and the results were actually surprising in that there were no failed attempts.
The second was within visual studio where I set up 20 threads to make 200000 simple GET httpweb requests to the server with a 0.5 sec interval. I logged the failed requests and there were about 3001 bad gateway errors(502).

Can anyone explain this or did the two tests differ entirely?

```
        url = "http://192.xxxxxxx"
        webrequest = TryCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        webrequest.Method = "GET"
        webrequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12 GTB7.1 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)"
        webrequest.Timeout = 60000
        webrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

        responseStream = webrequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
        responseData = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to compare the two. Here are the steps:

1. In StresStimulus select 200 users and 999 iterations to create the same as in VS load, around 200000 requests. Set think time between iteration to 1s and run the test. Double check that there are no errors.
2. Import StresStimulus test into Visual Studio. In Fiddler export test into Visual Studio Web Test file, add it to your VS test project and run test with load parameters as in StresStimulus. See if you get any errors.
3. Convert this test into a coded test and run again. If no errors, compare the code with your existing code and check how different they are.
4. Finally, you can route VS load traffic through Fiddler by [setting proxy 127.0.0.1:8888](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstswebtest/thread/59529893-1b8a-424e-8b23-cfd1c8963e1d), and then compare the requests with ones that are replayed by StresStimulus.

This should give you enough information to figure out why serve gives 502 to requests in one case but not in another.